# Getting whole repository structure from GitHub API using one request

Tags: github-api

Is it possible to somehow get information about whole repository using one request to github api or we have to recursively asking API for specific level?

According to this request: https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/terminal/contents?ref=master

we are only getting one level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [get the tree recursively](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree-recursively) using :

```
/repos/:owner/:repo/git/trees/:tree_sha?recursive=1
```

In your case it would be :

https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/terminal/git/trees/master?recursive=true

Answer (score 1):

You can make a request to here to see details about your branch:

- [https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches/{default_branch}](https://api.github.com/repos/%7Bowner%7D/%7Brepo%7D/branches/%7Bdefault_branch%7D)

In the response you will see "commit" field and inside of it there is "sha". Take that one put it in this request:

- [https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/trees/YOUR_SHA_GOES_HERE?recursive=1](https://api.github.com/repos/%7Bowner%7D/%7Brepo%7D/git/trees/YOUR_SHA_GOES_HERE?recursive=1)

You will receive every file under your repo like this.

Cheers!